# Help with ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :courses, :through => :attendances
end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
end

class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :course
end
```

Migrations:

```
create_table(:users) do |t|
  t.string :name
end

create_table(:courses) do |t|
  t.string :name
end

create_table(:attendances) do |t|
  t.references :user, :course
  t.date :date
end
```

**Question**

I would like to query:

- a list of all courses
- the date of a given user's last attendance (if any) for each course

What is the best way to tie the following together into a single query?

```
@courses = Course.all
@user = User.first
@attendances = @user.attendances.group('course_id').order('date DESC')
```

Note that there is a requirement to include courses that a user has not yet attended.

Any advice much appreciated.

**Update**

The result I am looking for is as follows:

```
Course            Last attended
===============================
Some course       2011-03-09
More training     Not Attended
Another course    2010-12-25
```

In SQL, I would write this query as:

```
SELECT * FROM courses AS c
LEFT OUTER JOIN attendances AS a ON a.course_id=c.id
WHERE a.user_id=1
GROUP BY a.course_id
ORDER BY a.date DESC;
```

I could always execute this SQL from within Rails, but I would prefer to avoid this and do things "the Rails way" if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Rails-Way" is to define small finders in the model and then to chain them in the controllers.

In class Attendance you could define a new method

```
def self.last_attendance
  maximum("date")
end
```

In class Corse ...

```
def self.ordered
  order("name DESC")
end
```

And so on. In the controller then, you use them in different combinations. The big advantage of this approach is

- Reusability of finder methods
- Decoupling of classes
- Better readability of code

Answer (score 1):

Your has_many through relation should be like this:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attendances
    has_many :courses, :through => :attendances
  end

  class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :attendances
    has_many :users, :through => :attendances
  end

  class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :course
  end
```

And please explain your problem. Because

```
@user.courses will give you only related courses
Course.all will give you all courses
```

Edited:

```
Course.find(:all, :joins => 'LEFT OUTER JOIN attendances ON attendances.course_id = 
courses.id', :conditions => ['attendances.user_id = ?', 1], :group => 
'attendances.course_id', :order => 'attendances.date DESC')
```

I hope it will work for you.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following. How does adding the extra `has_many :through` relation help?

Comment: Actually I just mentioned the right way of doing has_many through relationship. But I want you to explain your problem.

Comment: I have updated my question with an example of what I am trying to combine into one query.